# How to read a specific line of a request in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to read a certain part of a multiline text file in python3. How would I do this. This is my code so far but I specifically want to get the definition part of the get text.

```
import requests
page = requests.get('https://www.dictionary.com/browse/life')
count = 0
definition = ""
for line in page.text:
    if "content" in page.text:
        definition = line
        break
print(definition)
```

Comment: Do you have any working example ??

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) package which is helpful in parsing HTML content.

The page source shows there is a `<meta>` tag with a 'content' attribute:

```
<meta name="description" content="Life definition, the condition that distinguishes organisms from inorganic objects and dead organisms, being manifested by growth through metabolism, reproduction, and the power of adaptation to environment through changes originating internally. See more.">
```

With BeautifulSoup we can access that `meta` tag like a dictionary like this:

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

definition = soup.find('meta', {'name': "description"}).get('content')
print(definition)
```

Now `definition` contains:

```
>>> print(definition)
Life definition, the condition that distinguishes organisms from inorganic objects and dead organisms, being manifested by growth through metabolism, reproduction, and the power of adaptation to environment through changes originating internally. See more.
```